# This site can’t be reached after executing php script

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling, cpanel

I have a PHP script that is more than 400 lines of code. It was working fine, I made like couple of updates to it and now the browser is showing the following error:

```
This site can’t be reached
website.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

I have the following code to show and log errors:

```
//Set maximum execution time to max value
set_time_limit(0);

//Show errors on page
ini_set('display_errors',1);

//Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Log errors
ini_set('log_errors', TRUE);

//Change directory to file location
$fileDir = dirname(__FILE__);
chdir($fileDir);

//Save errors in errors.txt
ini_set('error_log', $fileDir . '/errors.txt');
```

So the errors should be saved in a file `errors.txt`, However I don't see any errors in that file.

The script is stopped after few seconds without any obvious error.

I checked the script for typo errors specially the updates I made, But I can't find any.

The script is hosted on Cpanel server. Is there is a way to debug or see where the script is stopped?

How to know if the script exceeded the maximum memory or CPU for example? Although it just stops after few seconds not minutes.

Comment: Most probably infinite loop or recursive redirection might be the cause

Comment: How can I check in case one of them?

Comment: Could infinite loop happen in like 40 or 50 seconds and cause this error?

Comment: No it can't but it can surely exhaust resources like RAM/cpu which makes OS terminate the process but since your logs show as empty this may not be the case